# PHP: How to get the last value of an array

Tags: php

The following PHP code I have:

```
foreach ($resources as $resource)
{
    // Iterates on the found IDs
    //echo 'Name of field: ' . $resource . ' - Value: ' . $resource->attributes() . '<br />';
    echo '<tr><td>'.$resource->attributes().'</td></tr>';
}
```

Returns:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

I only want to get the value of the last item: **8**
I've tried using:

```
echo end(end($resources->attributes()));
```

But this returns: **1**

Any ideas on how I can get **8** value?

Thanks

Comment: Have added a live demo to my answer as downvoters convinced me it may be wrong. Of course, it wasn't, so it was a downvote from another (probably less comprehensive) answerer.

Comment: @Jack Casas - put an end to this madness and choose the answer that helped you.

Comment: Is $resources an *array* or a *traversable object* ? since it points a sort of array of objects, it could be itself a traversable object. In this case end() will not work

Answer (score 6):

Try to use [end()](https://www.php.net/end),

```
end($resources)->attributes();
```

may this help you.

Answer (score 5):

```
end($resources)->attributes()
```

Answer (score 3):

you could also use [array_reverse()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) and then use $my_array[0]

```
      <?php
          $my_array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
          array_reverse($my_array);
          echo $my_array[0]; // echoes 8
      ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is:

```
end($resources)->attributes();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `end` twice, so the outermost `end` function is only working on a single element (return of inner `end` function). Try this instead:

```
echo end($resources)->attributes;
```

If your `attributes` is a function rather than a variable, you'd call:

```
echo end($resources)->attributes();
```

[Live demo here](http://eval.in/31368)

Comment: Because the previous version of the answer was wrong (you had `end($resources->attributes())`, which is incorrect). You've now updated it to be correct, so I've removed the downvote.

Comment: @Spudley - A downvote without a comment is pretty much valueless. If you see an answer is wrong, you should explain that it's wrong. In that case, it was a typo.

Comment: I was going to, but when I came back to comment you'd fixed it already.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:-

```
end($resources)->attributes()
```

Comment: Its duplicate of @deceze answer.

Answer (score 0):

$array[]=array( 'id'=>1, 'value'=>'val1' );

```
    $array[]=array( 'id'=>2, 'value'=>'val2' );

    $array[]=array( 'id'=>3, 'value'=>'val3' );

    $array[]=array( 'id'=>4, 'value'=>'val4' );
```

simplest way to get last value :

```
    $numb = count($array)-1;
    echo $array[$numb]['value'];
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use

```
$yourvar = count($yourarray)
```

than you could call it like

```
echo $yourarray[$yourvar];
```

that would directly out print last value in your array

Comment: That would work only if the array is 1-indexed, which really *never* happen in PHP